# How to make Rails helper methods available when calling render_to_string to render a template

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a ActiveMailer class, and inside I am sending emails with attached PDF template using the render_to_string method like this:

```
 def send_sales_order(email_service)
    @email_service = email_service
    @sales_order = SalesOrder.find_by_cid(email_service.order[:id])
    mail(:subject => I18n.t("custom_mailer.sales_order.subject", company_name: "test"), :to => @email_service.recipients) do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        attachments['purchase_order.pdf'] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
          render_to_string('sales_orders/show.pdf.erb', locals: {current_company: @sales_order.company})
        )
      end
    end
  end
```

Inside the show.pdf.erb template, I called my helper methods defined elsewhere such as the current_company method defined in ApplicationController like follow:

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      helper_method :current_company, :current_role

      def current_company
        return if current_user.nil?
        if session[:current_company_id].blank?
          session[:current_company_id] = current_user.companies.first.id.to_s
        end
        @current_company ||= Company.find(session[:current_company_id])
      end
```

But these helper methods are not available when I use the render_to_string method to render the template, is there a way around this?

Thanks

Comment: I am looking to solve the same problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ApplicationController.new.render_to_string` works for me

---

Comment: I get weird session-related errors. Are there alternatives?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33349408/37966 as a possible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Rails 5 you can use:

```
rendered_string = ApplicationController.render(
  template: 'invoice/show',
  assigns: { invoice: invoice }
)
```

This create a request-like object in a controller like env, assign a @invoice instance variable accessible in the template.

See documentation here for more options:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Renderer.html#method-i-render

Answer (score -2):

Just beat my head on the wall for a couple hours on this one. Finally found the `add_template_helper` method which did the trick.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  add_template_helper ApplicationHelper
  ...
  def foo
    @foo = render_to_string(partial: 'some_file.rb')
  end
end
```

This will make all methods from `ApplicationHelper` available, even when using `render_to_string` with a partial.