# Rails: Render view from outside controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create an HTML string using a view.  I would like to render this from a class that is not a controller.  How can I use the rails rendering engine outside a controller? Similar to how ActionMailer does?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Rails 5:

```
view = ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths)
view.render(file: 'template.html.erb')
```

In Rails 6.1:

```
lookup_context = ActionView::LookupContext.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths)
context = ActionView::Base.with_empty_template_cache.new(lookup_context, {}, nil)

renderer = ActionView::Renderer.new(lookup_context)
renderer.render(context, { file: 'app/views/template.html.erb' })
```

- `ActionView::Renderer.new()` takes a `lookup_context` arg, and `render()` method takes a `context`, so we set those up first
- `ActionView::Base` [is the default ActiveView context](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/24c8eb5dd1038df41ce84cd9f1acb965852ea449/actionview/lib/action_view/context.rb#L7), and must be initialized with `with_empty_template_cache` method, else `render()` will error
- The `{}, nil` are [required](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c5bf2b4736f2ddafbc477af5b9478dd7143e5466/actionview/lib/action_view/base.rb#L227) `assigns` and `controller` args, which used to default to `{}, nil` in Rails 5
- Rails 6.1 requires a full filepath `file: 'app/views/template.html'`, whereas Rails 5 only required the filename

Comment: This comment was hard for me to find, but resolves much of the confusion I was facing trying to update an ActionView::Base call to work in Rails 6.1.  If you wouldn't mind, could you add a few more details to the purpose of lookup_context, assigns, and *why* we have to init ActionView::Base with an empty_cache_template now?  These are all breaking changes for using ActionMailer to render a PDF and send a message with the PDF as an attachment, which was our implementation since Rails 3.

Answer (score 62):

Rails 5 and 6 support this in a much more convenient manner that handles creating a request and whatnot behind the scenes:

```
rendered_string = ApplicationController.render(
  template: 'users/show',
  assigns: { user: @user }
)
```

This renders `app/views/users/show.html.erb` and sets the `@user` instance variable so you don't need to make any changes to your template. It automatically uses the layout specified in `ApplicationController` (`application.html.erb` by default). [Full documentation can be found here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Renderer.html).

[The test shows a handful of additional options and approaches.](https://github.com/brainopia/rails/blob/action_view_render/actionpack/test/controller/renderer_test.rb)

Comment: If any one would like to generate text without the controller, look for: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-c-new with this, you don't have to create the logic inside the `views` directory.

Comment: @EduardoSantana That's great if you have a plain ERB template you want to render, but it won't render ActionView views. I.e., you don't get instance variables, partial rendering, helper methods, etc.

Comment: Using controller classes trigged warden and authentication issues.   This worked for me: 
    `ActionView::Base.new('app/views').render(file: 'invoices/show', locals: {invoiceObjIn: inv}, layout: 'layouts/invoice')`

Comment: I have this error: `Devise could not find the 'Warden::Proxy' instance on your request environment.`. How do you solve this?

Comment: @alagaesia Please open a new question instead of commenting when you have a problem so that others can jump in and help.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  In my case the templates are using local variables instead of instance variables, so substituting `locals` for `assigns` worked for me.

Answer (score 47):

You can use [ActionView::Base](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Base/new/class) to achieve this.

```
view = ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths, {})
view.render(file: 'template.html.erb')
```

The [ActionView::Base](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Base/new/class) initialize takes:

1. A context, representing the template search paths
2. An `assigns` hash, providing the variables for the template

If you would like to include helpers, you can use class_eval to include them:

```
view.class_eval do
  include ApplicationHelper
  # any other custom helpers can be included here
end
```

Comment: Using ActionView::Base is the best answer, IMO.  I'd probably go a small step further and subclass it for convenience, but that's just me.  I've never gotten AbstractController to work the way that others describe, but maybe my version of Rails is too recent.  Either way, this way feels less dirty.

Comment: What about nested layouts ?

Comment: To render with layout: `view.render(file: 'template.html.erb', layout: 'layouts/layout.html.erb')`

Answer (score 7):

There is no need to over bloat your app with too many gems. As we know ERB is already included in your Rails app.

```
@jdf = JDF.new
@job = ERB.new(File.read(Rails.root + "app/views/entries/job.xml.erb"))
result =  @job.result(binding)
```

Above there is snippet of code of an app I'm working on.

- `@jdf` is a object to be evaluated in the `erb` view.
- In my case I needed to render `xml`.
- `result` is a string to be saved or sent anywhere you like.

Comment: This is good unless you depend on helpers like `link_to` etc.

Answer (score 3):

"I'm trying to create an HTML string using a view." -- If you mean you're in the context of a view template, then just use a helper method or render a partial.

If you're in some other "Plain Old Ruby Object", then keep in mind you're free to use the ERB module directly:

```
erb = ERB.new("path/to/template")
result = erb.result(binding)
```

The trick is getting that 'binding' object that gives the context for the code in the template. ActionController and other Rails classes expose it for free, but I couldn't find a reference that explains where it comes from.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-i-result

Comment: I'm doing this, but there seems to be a problem with using the helpers in my erb file, how would you go about that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62211842/rails-how-to-use-helpers-with-erb-new-in-service?noredirect=1#comment110027118_62211842

Answer (score 3):

Calling directly render method on ApplicationController may raise error

```
 Helper Devise: could not find the `Warden::Proxy` instance on request environment
```

Instead we can use ApplicationController.renderer.render like

```
 rendered_string = ApplicationController.renderer.render(
     partial: 'users/show',
     locals: { user: user }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Technically, `ActionMailer` is a subclass implementation of `AbstractController::Base`. If you want to implement this functionality on your own, you'll likely want to inherit from `AbstractController::Base` as well.

There is a good blog post here: https://www.amberbit.com/blog/2011/12/27/render-views-and-partials-outside-controllers-in-rails-3/ that explains the steps required.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I ended up finding
this handy gem that makes this a breeze:

https://github.com/yappbox/render_anywhere

Comment: The referenced library hasn't been updated since 2015 and is incompatible with Rails 4 and 5.

Comment: First line from that gem's README.md file (since Nov 08, 2019): DEPRECATED: This gem is no longer needed as of Rails 5. Use ActionController::Renderer instead.

Answer (score -3):

Best to render the view using a controller, as that's what they're for, and *then* convert it to a string, as that is your ultimate goal.

```
require 'open-uri'
html = open(url, &:read)
```

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*