# Getting access to helper methods inside ApplicationController.new.render_to_string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 app. Inside my `FooController`, I am generating some html content via:

```
ApplicationController.new.render_to_string("some_haml_file", locals: {foo: "bar"}, layout: false)
```

Inside `some_haml_file.html.haml` I need to perform some complicated logic, so leveraging helper methods, or something that corresponds to it, would help a lot. A `.rb` file of some kind to include.

Is it possible? I suspect that the question may have been answered in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959425/how-to-make-rails-helper-methods-available-when-calling-render-to-string-to-rend/47470689#47470689), but I honestly don't understand it.

Comment: You can perform your complicated logic right here, in controller, and pass the result to `locals` hash

Comment: @nattfodd if I need to loop through multiple items and perform the same logic on them it's more convenient to have it in a helper-like setting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's a `helpers` folder in your application. Create a new module there that's named `*anything*Helper`, e.g. `FooHelper`. The filename should be `foo_helper.rb` in that case.

File's contents would be

```
module FooHelper
   def useful_function
   end
end
```

Then you can use `useful_function` in your HAML.

Comment: But how do I access it in the haml file? Please note that it is not rendered like usual, but instead with `ApplicationController.new.render_to_string`.

Comment: You just call it like `useful_function`, all helper modules are automatically available in templates. I would assume that it is still the case when using `render_to_string`